# What is the meaning of LLC-prefetch-misses perf event

Tags: linux, caching, perf, prefetch

I'm trying to understand the meaning of the `LLC-prefetch-misses` perf event for Sandy Bridge.

From linux kernel [source](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6.15/source/arch/x86/events/intel/core.c#L30) I see the definition of the event:

```
[ C(OP_PREFETCH) ] = {
    [ C(RESULT_ACCESS) ] = SNB_DMND_PREFETCH|SNB_L3_ACCESS,
    [ C(RESULT_MISS)   ] = SNB_DMND_PREFETCH|SNB_L3_MISS,
},
```

where:
`SNB_DMND_PREFETCH = (SNB_PF_DATA_RD|SNB_PF_RFO)` points to bits 4-5 of the event register, while
`SNB_L3_MISS = (SNB_DRAM_ANY|SNB_NON_DRAM)` points to bits 22-36 of the event register.

Reading [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/download/intel-64-and-ia-32-architectures-sdm-combined-volumes-1-2a-2b-2c-2d-3a-3b-3c-3d-and-4.html), volume 3, chapter 18.3.4.5, I find that:

`SNB_DMND_PREFETCH` stand for the "Request_Type" and `SNB_L3_MISS` stand for the "Response_Type" fields of the `MSR_OFFCORE_RSP_x` Event Registers

Request:

[image]

Response:

[image]
[image]

However, I'm not able to understand the meaning of the "Response" in the context of prefetching.

Moreover, I found this definition in some courses [slides](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/%7Ealaa/courses/ece587/spring2012/notes/prefetching.pdf):

`Prefetch Hit: Prefetched line that was hit in the cache before being replaced (miss avoided)`

`Prefetch Miss: Prefetched line that was replaced before being accessed`

Any suggestions regarding the meaning of `LLC-prefetch` and `LLC-prefetch-misses` events? Are the above definitions relevant?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The event `LLC-prefetch-misses` occurs for an L2 hardware prefetch of any type (DATA_RD or RFO) where the target cache line was not supplied from a CPU cache. An L2 hardware prefetch is generated only when the target line doesn't exist in the same L2 cache in the required coherence state (E or M, for an RFO prefetch, or S, for a DATA_RD prefetch).

Processing a prefetch transaction may require snooping the private caches of other cores in the same NUMA domain or snooping caches in other NUMA domains. The `SNB_DRAM_ANY` flag in the event definition means that the event includes all snooping cases. The only two requirements for an event of type `LLC-prefetch-misses` is that it's an L2 hardware prefetch request and that the supplier is not a CPU cache. The supplier in this case is usually a local or remote DRAM controller.

The event `LLC-prefetch` is inclusive of `LLC-prefetch-misses` in the sense that it includes the cases where the supplier is a CPU data cache (L3, L2 , or L1D). An L2 prefetch that hits in the L3 is counted by `LLC-prefetch` but not by `LLC-prefetch-misses`. The `LLC-prefetch` count is at least as large `LLC-prefetch-misses`.